# Gremlin JavaScript client doesn't throw exception on socket disconnection

Tags: gremlin

I'm using the gremlin package version 3.5.2 with NodeJS.
If the server disconnects while the client waits for a query result from the server (await t.next()), the promise never finishes and the calling code gets stuck forever.
I've used the addListener function to register on "log" events and I see the client recognizes the socket was closed, but it doesn't throw an exception for ongoing requests.
I'm looking for a solution that will enable my server to handle such situations without getting stuck and without any resource leaks.

There is a ticket for it at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2754
You can find in the ticket a small program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is this your problem? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2708

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I think it is similar, but in my case, it happens after a connection was already established and a request was sent. I'm able to reproduce it very easily by stopping the Tinkerpop server docker in the middle of work. New requests will fail but existing ones hangs forever. @stephen mallette

Comment: i suggest you add to a comment to that ticket with the specific of your issue and how to recreate it.

Comment: Added a comment to the ticket with a short NodeJS program to reproduce it.